# Android WebView: scrollIntoView not working on epub pagebreak span

Tags: android, html, scroll, android-webview

My app features a WebView where a local HTML page is loaded.

The page has

```
<span id="page752" epub:type="pagebreak">752</span>
```

somewhere embedded in text.

I get the element with id="page752" by means of getElementById function, then I call 
    element.scrollIntoView(true);
but it doesn't work, that is, no scroll is performed.

Note that the element text ("725") is not displayed in the WebView. Maybe this is related to the scroll not being performed.

How to make the span able to scrollIntoView?

Comment: Is the WebView actually scrollable? Are you loading it in wrap_contents mode by any chance?

Comment: It is scrollable, AFAIK it is not loaded with that paramater as you say; however I solved with a trick: if a suitable selection range is created with the span as the start element, I am able to get the y coordinate I need from range rects

Comment: fair enough. Out of curiosity - which version of the WebView were you using? If it's a recent one this may be a bug that can be fixed.

Comment: I have not checked every version because the workaround was successful, I think at least Android 4.0.3 WebView behaves that way, my app is min API level=12 target API level=12 (Android 3.1), however.

Comment: Thanks! 4.0.3 is definitely too old to fix, sorry!